# Meteor - "this" return a function as string in a template event

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I set a data field with Iron router containing 2 fields `quizz`and `questions`:

```
Router.route('/profile/quizz/:_id/edit', {
    template: 'quizzEdit',
    name: 'quizzEdit',
    data: function(){
        var id = this.params._id;
        return{
            quizz: function(){
                return Quizz.findOne({_id: id});
            },
            questions: function(){
                return Questions.find({});
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In my template's submit event, I want to get values from my fields, this is what I do:

```
Template.quizzEdit.events({
    "submit .new-question": function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(this.quizz);

        event.target.name.value= "";
    }
});
```

The problem is `console.log(this.quizz)`, I would like to log my MongoDB object so I can access things like `this.quizz._id`, but instead what is log a string containing my router's source code:

```
function() {     // 41
    return Quizz.findOne({ _id: id });   // 42
}
```

Here is an image of my chrome console:

[Google console http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/385623Capture.png](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/385623Capture.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling function:

```
console.log(this.quizz());
```

Comment: It seems to work using quizz()... why can't I use this.quizz ?

Comment: quizz is a reference to a function. You need to execute the function to get the data.